# Serialising XForm instances as SOAPAttach attachments

Tags: javascript, dom, soap, xforms

I wish to submit an XForms instance to a web service as a [SOAPAttach](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-attachments-20001211) attachment. However, from the XForms 1.1 specification:

- [11.11.3 SOAP HTTP Binding](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#SOAP-HTTP-Binding)

  > The `method` attribute of the `submission` [must](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#intro-reading) be set to `get` or `post` in order to access the SOAP HTTP binding.

  I understand this to mean that the `multipart-post` method (required for SOAPAttach) cannot be used with the SOAP HTTP binding?
- [11.9.6 Serialization as multipart/related](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#serialize-multipart)

  > - Subsequent part requirements
  >
  >   - One part for each node with a datatype of `xsd:anyURI` populated by upload with:

  Since it explicitly states "populated by upload", I take this to mean that XML instance data or other generated content can only appear in the first body part (contrary to the requirements of SOAPAttach).

Am I correct in understanding that each of these restrictions make it impossible to (natively) submit an XForms instance as such an attachment; and, therefore, that one must generate such a serialization oneself (e.g. by handling the `xforms-submit-serialize` event)?  Is there a standard way to do so, or a library that could help?

Answer (score 2):

I am not a SOAP expert, but I think you are right.

Orbeon Forms handles the "populated by upload" requirement by checking that `xforms:upload` controls are bound to the nodes of the instance to submit, so yes for now I think that the XForms 1.1 is unfortunately tied to upload.

On the other hand, it doesn't seem like XForms implementations should be very far from from being able to doing this natively, as they should already support `multipart/related` with uploaded files as attachments, as you point out.

Doing your own serialization seems like a lot of work.

Comment: Agreed that it seems like a lot of work, but I'm struggling to see any other way around it.  I can't even access the serialization X-Forms would have otherwise used in order to perform a few simple manipulations to obtain my desired result!  Also, thanks for tidying up my question - but on this side of the pond we definitely spell it "serialisation" ;P

Comment: Sorry about the incorrect correction. I mainly wanted to fix "XForms" ;) In order to reuse the code already in place, you would have to go into Java land, and enhance [XFormsModelSubmission.java](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/java/org/orbeon/oxf/xforms/submission/XFormsModelSubmission.java)