# Structure of an XForms instance for a multipart/form-data submission

Tags: curl, solr, orbeon, xforms

I am having some trouble figuring out how to submit a binary file via an XForms submission with the multipart/form-data serialization. For some background, I am attempting to post document files (e.g., PDFs) into Apache Solr with the [ExtractingRequestHandler](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler#Getting_Started_with_the_Solr_Example). I am able to successfully post with CURL on the command line, but I am having difficulty posting from the XForms engine (specifically, I am using Orbeon).

Here is my submission:

```
<xforms:submission 
    id="extract-document"
    action="{instance('config')/solr}update/extract?literal.id={instance('doc')/mods:mods/mods:recordInfo/mods:recordIdentifier}&amp;fmap.content=text"
    ref="instance('form-data')"
    replace="none" 
    method="post" 
    serialization="multipart/form-data">
```

My form-data instance is:

```
<xforms:instance id="form-data">
    <formData>
        <myFile
            xsi:type="xs:anyURI" 
            filename="file.pdf" 
            size="2957563" 
            mediatype="application/pdf">file:/path/to/file.pdf</myFile>
    </formData>
</xforms:instance>
```

I have tried excluding the attributes from the myFile element, but the submission fails. I just have no idea how to construct the form-data instance.

Thanks for the help.

---

Update 8 Aug 2017: The issue of posting via multipart/form-data in the xforms:submission has never been truly resolved. I am attempting to attach an XML file when posting form data to a web service, but it isn't being attached, according to the W3C specification for the [multipart/form-data XForms instance model](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-xforms-20031014/slice11.html#serialize-form-data).

I created a fully-functional test that fails, yielding a response that the file has not been attached, even though the `<fname>` input has been correctly bound to an xforms:upload control. I can verify that the first portion of the spec ("Each element that has exactly one text node child is selected for inclusion.") does function when passing authentication information to the web service, as I am not getting an error about a missing username or password within event('response-body') on xforms-submit-error.

Here is the Gist: https://gist.github.com/ewg118/c182a8b4a69ff57bdb6b025950332e55

The XML file should be attached according to the XForms spec (if I've done everything correctly), but it doesn't seem to be working. I am testing on Orbeon 2017.1, but it also didn't work on a late 2015 build.

Comment: Is this with Orbeon Forms?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure if there is an Orbeon specific solution.

Comment: It's possible to serialize as bytes by using  `application/octet-stream` as serialization as [documented here](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-advanced-submissions#TOC-Submitting-binary-content). But that is different from `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: I wasn't able to PUT data into Solr with application/octet-stream, but that led me into experimenting with base64 encoding the binary files and posting them in. I could post them, but couldn't decode them back. Eventually I found that the solution was to use the stream.url request parameter, such as the example in http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/en/assets/1/event/61/Solr%20Application%20Development%20Tutorial%20Presentation.pdf. These parameters are not well documented in the Solr wiki for the ExtractingRequestHandler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialising XForm instances as SOAPAttach attachments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404253/serialising-xform-instances-as-soapattach-attachments)